# AWS S3 bucket policy notprincipal deny

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My goal is to create exclusive access to a bucket for one IAM user, and to maintain that exclusivity easily as new iam users and groups are added. The user is outside of my control and has a managed policy attached to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "FullTestBucketS3Access",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have applied a bucket policy to the bucket that needs to exclude all users except one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/myuser"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am finding that the mask provided by the NotPrincipal part of the deny statement is not working. All users are denied the ability to take the action specified in the deny policy. What should I be looking at to work this out?

Comment: The first policy shown is not valid (trailing comma after second resource). Are you sure that this is actually what's configured?

Comment: Also, I just tried this and it seemed to work (my targeted IAM user was able to delete objects in the bucket, but no other IAM users were allowed to).